# Why does this keep printing if I

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to encrypt a message and after one letter is encrypted the encrypted letter bank is shifted from the innerRotorClockWise method. When I call it I get the output below. (message is just one letter in this case) I'm trying to just get back one while it changes the bank. Do you guys know why it loops?

Inner Index Number: 20

Inner Index Number: 20 21

Inner Index Number: 20 21 22

Inner Index Number: 20 21 22 23

Inner Index Number: 20 21 22 23 24

Inner Index Number: 20 21 22 23 24 25

Inner Index Number: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

When I don't called the method I get:

Inner Index Number: 20

```
for(int i = 0; i < encryptMessageArray.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < innerRotorClockWise.length; j++){

        if(encryptMessageArray[i].equals(innerRotorClockWise[j])){
            indexNumber = indexNumber + j +  " ";
            //encrypt the first letter
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Inner Index Number: " + indexNumber);
            System.out.println("");

            innerRotorClockWise(); //change theencrypted letter bank
                                   // repeat
```

This is the innerRotorClockWise method.

```
public void innerRotorClockWise(){

int lastIndex = innerRotorClockWise.length - 1; 

String oldLast = innerRotorClockWise[lastIndex]; 


for (int i = lastIndex; i != 0; i--) 
    innerRotorClockWise[i] = innerRotorClockWise[i - 1];

    innerRotorClockWise[0] = oldLast;
```

Comment: Well, I see `for loop`, so these might be the reason, depending on your condition. Use the debugger to see what happen there. We don't have enough to reproduce this, you can write a [mcve] and the expected behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got what you are trying to do, it appears you should call `innerRotorClockWise()` in the outer loop (after you finish encrypting the current letter). In addition, you should probably break from the inner loop once you find a match :

```
for(int i = 0; i < encryptMessageArray.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < innerRotorClockWise.length; j++) {
        if(encryptMessageArray[i].equals(innerRotorClockWise[j])) {
            indexNumber = indexNumber + j +  " ";
            //encrypt the first letter
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Inner Index Number: " + indexNumber);
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        }
    }
    innerRotorClockWise(); //change theencrypted letter bank
                           // repeat
}
```